# What's the difference between Arena Quests and Challenge Quests?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

The guild member on the far right in the marina hands out *Arena Quests* and *Challenge Quests*. But the same quests are in both lists, and when I finished a quest in one it also checked it off in the other. What's the difference between these quest lists?

Comment: If the quests are identical, and if you beat one in one place, it checks in the other, maybe there's just two access points to the quest list? But what do I know, I only played MHFU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that they are exactly the same, until you enter high rank (HR3).

Once you do, *Challenge Quests* changes to show, uh, challenge quests. The arena quests are no longer listed under it.